# how to send array of strings as argument in graphql query

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to send array of strings as a query to my springboot based server,but the following query does not work `ExecutionResult execute = graphQLService.getGraphQL().execute("{my_func{my_var:[\"abc\"]}{my_var2}}");`

here is my schema file

```
schema {
   query: Query
   mutation: Mutation
 }

type Query {
   my_func(
     my_var: [String]
        ) : [object]
 }

type object{
    my_var: String,
    my_var2: String,
 }
```

this is the error

```
Query failed to parse : '{my_func{my_var:["abc"}]}{my_var2}}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your query is not correct . It should be :

```
{
  my_func (my_var:["abc"]) {
    my_var2
  }
}
```

You should use round brackets `()` instead of curly brackets `{}` for specifying the field argument in the query.